# Defining work hours and weekends for datetime manipulation

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to somehow define working hours for business days, and weekends, for inputting DATETIME values (stored procedure, or something)?
Example:
2 datetime columns, timestart and timestop. The difference between them is always 1 hour, but if it's, for an example timestart = 20:30:00 Friday, the timestop should equal 07:30:00 Monday, because working hours end at 21:00:00 Friday, and the work starts at Monday - 07:00:00.

Sorry for the long explanation, and sorry for not having any code, I googled everything and couldn't find a working solution...

Comment: Do you want the timestop value to be automatically calculated when the timestart value is entered?

Comment: The question itself is kinda flat... But yes its possible, i wouldn't store two values in the db. Since most values will only differ by one hour. When you retrieve from db, check what time it is and if its a weekday/weekend and then set the timestop.

Comment: @SomeSillyName No, the values are predefined, timestart is current time, and timestop is one hour in advance. It's an android app, which is accessing some php script. I did all the java and php coding, but I can't put my finger on this one...
@ apelsinapa That isn't really convenient, because the times are for some service which is being provided, at the moment of generating the time.